# How doesThymeleaf validate checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

If I have the following HTML and javascript code

```
<form action="../" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">
    <p><input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_1" value="This..."> This...</p>
    <p><input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_2" value="That..."> That...</p>
    <p><input type="CHECKBOX" name="CHECKBOX_3" value="...and The Other"> ...and The Other</p>
    <p><input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit!"></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
    if (
    theForm.CHECKBOX_1.checked == false &&
    theForm.CHECKBOX_2.checked == false &&
    theForm.CHECKBOX_3.checked == false) 
    {
        alert ('You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes!');
        return false;
    } else {    
        return true;
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Can Thymeleaf validate the above code without using JavaScript?

Of course I can validate in the controller and send message back. But wonder if it can be done in the front end?

Or this is beyond what Thymeleaf can do and I still use JavaScript code to do such validation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this can either be done in controller or via javascript, unfortunately Thymeleaf cannot do this.

If you want to do on client side, then use JavaScript.
If you want to do on server side, then use controller.